# Ionic push notification and badge using fcm plugin

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, icons, push, badge

Good day everybody,

I'm so newbie with ionic and apps and I'm trying integrate a badge icon in ios with this framework but I can't how do it.

In app.js I have push notification integrate, and I want when a push notification is received, the badge icon is counting the number notification.

I'm using a plugin for push notification called "cordova plugin fcm". Can this plugin add this badge? Have I use other plugin? How can I integrate it?

Thanks a lot for all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin can get you in action:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge

you just need to integrate this with the fcm plugin and you're good to go.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge this plugin works fine for setting the badge.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast reply. I write the following code, but I don't know if its correct or not (I'm really so newbie)

```
        FCMPlugin.onNotification(
            function(data) {
                APPService.forceToDownloadAgain();
                Notificaciones.addNotification(data);
                console.log(data);
                if (data.wasTapped) {
                    //Received in device tray. Tapped by user
                    $state.go('global.notifies');
                    cordova.plugins.notification.badge.increase();
                } else {
                    //Received in foreground. Advice to user
                    $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: 'Notificación recibida',
                        template: 'Te gustaría ver la notificación que has recibido?'
                    }).then(function(res) {
                        if (res) {
                            $state.go('global.notifies');
                            cordova.plugins.notification.badge.clear();
                        }
                    });

                }

            },
            function(msg) {
                //OK
            },
            function(err) {
                //ERROR
            }
        );
```